# Solution of a first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $$y'-\frac yx=\sin x,\quad y(1)=0$$ and show that $\lim_ {x\to \infty} y(x)/x$ is finite.

I solved the equation and got this:

$$y=x\int \frac{\sin x}{x}\,  dx + C  .$$

I have no clue however, how to find the constant and the limit.

Comment: If $y(x)=x\int_c^x\frac{\sin t}{t}\mathrm{d}t+C$ for some constant c, then the initial condition is $0=y(1)=\int_c^1\frac{\sin t}{t}\mathrm{d}t+C$ and then $C=-\int_c^1\frac{\sin t}{t}\mathrm{d}t$. But then, $y'(x)-\frac{y}{x}=\sin x+\int_c^1\frac{\sin t}{xt}\mathrm{d}t$, thus we must take $c=1$, giving us $C=0$ and $y(x)=x\int_1^x\frac{\sin t}{t}\mathrm{d}t$. For the limit, use the fact that $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin t}{t}\mathrm{d}t$ is finite (and is a well known constant).

Comment: I am assuming you was not intending the double quote mark?

Comment: your solution containes the Bessel function

Comment: @Nicolas Thanx a lot. Got the answer I wanted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=vx$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{y}{x}=\sin x$

$v+x\frac{dv}{dx}-v=\sin x$

$\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{\sin x}{x}$

$\int dv=\int \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$

Let $/\int \frac{\sin x}{x}dx=I$

$I=\sin x \ln x+\int \ln x \cos x dx$

$I=\sin x \ln x+ \sin x \ln x-\int \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$

$2I=2\sin x \ln x$

$I=\sin x \ln x$

Hence $\int dv=\int \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$

$v=\sin x \ln x+C$

$\frac{y}{x}=\sin x \ln x+C$

When $x=1,y=0$

C=0.

$y=x\sin x \ln x$